# Django join multiple models using django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

I googled and read many articles but got confused in multiple table join.
My models looks like-

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Active', choices=status)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % ( self.category_name)

class ProductSubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory)
    sub_category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='subcategory', null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Active', choices=status)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % ( self.sub_category_name)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductSubCategory)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    product_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    # is_discountable = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='Yes', choices=option)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Active', choices=status)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % ( self.product_name)

class ProductColor(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    product_color = models.ForeignKey(Color, related_name='product_color_id', blank=True, null=True)
    product_size = models.ForeignKey(Size, related_name='product_size_id', blank=True, null=True)


class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
```

Now in views, I want to get the product filters according to category and sub-category having all the images and colors. Query is something like-

```
SELECT product.*, productcolor.*, productimage.* FROM product
LEFT JOIN productcolor ON productcolor.product_id = product.id 
LEFT JOIN productcolor.product_id = product.id 
LEFT JOIN productimage ON productimage.product_id = product.id 
WHERE product.category_id=1 and product.sub_category_id=1
```

Comment: Your need seems broad. Can you elaborate? Provide with examples.

Comment: @vishes_shell just updated the question.

Comment: @vishes_shell I have tried but still not getting the convient solution :(

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I tried a lot but output is not as expected. :(

Comment: What is your desired output and what is the difference with what you get?

Comment: ProductImages.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('product', queryset=Product.objects.filter(category=category_id.id, sub_category=sub_category_id.id).all())).all()

I tried other approaches also but either I am getting Product model data or ProductImages data.

I want Product model data as well Product Images

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to your SQL, this will do.

```
Product.objects.filter(category=<category>, sub_category=<sub_category>) \
    .prefetch_related('productcolor_set', 'productimages_set')
```

This query will prefetch all (with [`.prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)) `ProductColor` and `ProductImages` related to `Product` that have your `<category>` and `<sub_category>`, they would be stored in `productcolor_set` and `productimages_set` respectively.

Also i would suggest to rename your `ProductImages` model to `ProductImage` because it represents only one product image.

Comment: getting error saying - Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'productimages_set', 'productcolor_set'. Choices are: category, sub_category

Comment: @V.Khakhil my bad, morning mistakes, updated answer.

Comment: both prefetch_related and select_related selecting only from Product with where condition.
SELECT `cart_product`.`id`, `cart_product`.`category_id`, `cart_product`.`sub_category_id`, `cart_product`.`ISBN`, `cart_product`.`product_name`, `cart_product`.`product_price`, `cart_product`.`product_description`, `cart_product`.`product_rating`, `cart_product`.`created_at`, `cart_product`.`updated_at`, `cart_product`.`status` FROM `cart_product` WHERE (`cart_product`.`category_id` = 1 AND `cart_product`.`sub_category_id` = 1)

Comment: @V.Khakhil it's more than that, you should read docs for [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) that i've already attached to answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
ProductCategory.productsubcategory_set.all()
```